# Implementing Forms Authentifcation in Intranet web-app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to develop an Intranet web-app via ASP.NET MVC 4 (C#). Using this configuration, I can't have the default generated AccountController and configurations related. Is it possible to implement that type of `Forms authentication` in an Intranet web-app ? and how, please ?

If it's not possible, I thought to create a Filter that redirects all requests to the LogInController, but the question here is How to recognize if a user has been identified or not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default template possibly assumes that an intranet application uses `Windows` authentication. If this is so, create an **internet** application from the template instead, which sets up the forms authentication. Also have a membership provider, a custom one or the builtin `ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider` if you want to authenticate users in a local AD.

From this moment, develop your application just like it was an internet application but then deploy it locally.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Then, how can I benefit from a Windows Authentication and Forms Authentication, please ?

Comment: You can't have both. Windows Authentication means that users will not be prompted for credentials in the local intranet. Forms means that users will have to provide their Active Directory login and password.